# Is it good practice to make your navigation buttons form buttons?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to create a classes pages. The way i want to approach is that based on what class you have chosen, the class template will populate based with content based on the class that you've chosen. I want to create one class template and let the rest of the content come from the database, the only way to do this is by making the navigating button a form button am I right or is there a more efficient way? I am using python django for server side

ie

```
 <button type="submit" value="math">
```

Answer (score 0):

This would imply that your page will reload every time you click, a more elegant approach would be to use some JavaScript and some AJAX like this `onclick="someFunction()"` and after that you use some ajax to populate your page.